# split the url from the / with php

Tags: php, url, split

What would be the best way to split URL http://www.mysite.com/?name

How to split the /?name from the above url and be able to put in a id from the server.  The ids are already on the server I just need to change this so that someone with that id could put in:

http://www.mysite.com/username.

Comment: are you using a framework?

Comment: can you please as expected url

Comment: yeah good question by @Gian Acuna. You may get the url segment you dont need to use `id`, every framework has own way to do it. In CI '$this->uri->segment(#of segment);'

Comment: not using framework but just need to get the php to work accordingly with wordpress in the header.php file.  it will not let me upload a .htaccess file

Answer (score 2):

First, you should use URL rewriting to convert all the virtual addresses into script calls. Like `www.mysite.com/username` is actually served as `www.mysite.com/?name=username`. Inside the script, you would simply access the `name` variable from GET parameters.

There are thousands of tutorials available on the net, this one seems good enough : http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: what if i cannot access the .htaccess file because it is not writable and it is in a wordpress?

Answer (score 2):

use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) output is

> scheme - e.g. http
>
> host
>
> port
>
> user
>
> pass
>
> path
>
> query - after the question mark ?
>
> fragment - after the hashmark #

like

```
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor';

print_r(parse_url($url));
```

output

```
Array
(
   [scheme] => http
   [host] => hostname
   [user] => username
   [pass] => password
   [path] => /path
   [query] => arg=value
   [fragment] => anchor
)
```

Comment: in which php file exactly are you going to put this code (assuming the `username` part is the varying bit in the address)?

Comment: this is a example it can parse every url

Comment: I am going to put it in header.php if I can.  This is in a wordpress.  I have also tried the .htaccess but it is not writable and I cannot see it via ftp in the root folder.